# wait for promise to be resolved in catch of the calling promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a *associateNewUserToProject* function as below, to create the an association of the project and the user. I need to delete the user if there is any exception in the *addUserToProject* service.

```
function createNewUserFailureHandler (user) {
   return function (error) {
       UserService.deleteUser(user.userId);
   }; 
}
function associateNewUserToProject(responses, project) {
   var promises = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
      var failureHandler = createNewUserFailureHandler(responses[i][0].data);
      promises.push(ProjectService.addUserToProject(project.projectId, responses[i][0].data)
        .catch(failureHandler));
   }
   $q.all(promises).then(function () {
       onSave(responses);
   });
}
function deleteUser (userId) {
   var request = {
       method: 'DELETE',
       url: UrlBuilderService.buildApiUrl('user', String(userId))
   };
   return $http(request);
}
```

This works without any issues. But I want to wait for the *deleteUser* service to resolve, which I am not able to figure out.

How can I create a promise in the catch function and wait for the catch-promise to be resolved in case of exception? I want to call onSave() method after the *deleteUser* service function is resolved in case of exception.

Comment: Could you share `UserService.deleteUser()` code? Is it a http promise?

Comment: @MartinGottweis I have updated the question with the _deleteUser_ service function. It uses the $http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the `createNewUserFailureHandler` is returning an empty function not a promise.

Just do this and it should work fine:

```
function createNewUserFailureHandler (user) {
    return function (error) {
        return UserService.deleteUser(user.userId);
    }; 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I missed this return statement!!! Now its working as expected! :)

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with your project.